# Find and add property to an object for an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an object and it has a property that is an array of other objects that contains (among other properties) an ID.

Say like

```
car = {
    id: number
    model: string
    company: object
}
```

where `company = {id: number, name: string}`

Now, I want to add to a company that produces this car a phone number. But not to all companies, only for the company with ID = 5.

My first idea was to define `company` as `Map<number, object>()`, but I need to use arrays. What's is the most efficient way to achieve this.

I was thinking of:

1. Use `filter` to find my company by ID
2. Add the new property to the object returned above
3. Use `indexOf` and `splice` to remove the company from the array
4. Push the object from `2` back in the array

But this process seems a bit overcomplicated. Is there a better, faster way?

Comment: `[].find` could be used. No need to splice and re-push the object in array. Object is mutable...

Comment: I don't think `filter` would be the best, I'd use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if the company Id's are unique anyway

Comment: Do cars produced by the same company really share the same company object, or do they have a company objects that are distinct but just happen to have the same id and name?

Comment: Question like `What's the best solution?` and `Is there a better, faster way?` might be just `primarily opinion-based` questions. You already listed several possible options, choose one and get your code working. If you have issues with the code, post your code and we have a look at it. If you get it working but want to know what is the `best or better` solution you might have to ask that over at [**https://codereview.stackexchange.com**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. Indeed `find` was the better option. I forgot this exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding correctly, `car.company` is an array, right?

You can directly add the new property to the object within the array. No need to extract it and then push it back to the array.

**Here's how I would do it:**

> 1. Use `map()` to convert company object array into just the ids.
> 2. Find the index of your wanted id by using `indexOf` on the array of ids from step 1.
> 3. Set new property directly to the object at the index found in step 2.

**If we start with this, for example:**

```
var car = {
  company: [
    { id: 4, name: 'Lamborghini' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Honda' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Ferrari' }
  ]
}
```

**This function would add a phone number for the specified company id:**

```
function addPhone (companyID,phoneNumber){

  // Map company array and convert each company object into just ids
  var ids = car.company.map( function(c){ return c.id });

  // Find index of specified id
  var index = ids.indexOf(companyID)

  // Set the phone for the object at the corresponding index found above
  car.company[index].phone = phoneNumber

}
```

**So running `addPhone(5,'123-456-7890')`, results in this:**

```
var car = {
  company: [
    { id: 4, name: 'Lamborghini' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Honda', phone: '123-456-7890' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Ferrari' }
  ]
}
```

Ultra-compact / Not-readable / One-liner version (just for the hell of it):

```
car.company[car.company.map(function(c){ return c.id }).indexOf(companyID)].phone = phoneNumber

// ES6
car.company[car.company.map(c => c.id).indexOf(companyID)].phone = phoneNumber
```